# How can I preserve the background and foreground color of a DataGridView.DefaultCellStyle when it is selected?

Tags: c#, datagridview

[image: Unselected]
[image: Selected]

When the row in the datagridview is selected the background color of the row gets overridden and the user cannot determine which state the row is in.

Is there a way to not change the background color of the row when selected?

Comment: No, but you can set the selectioncolors: `DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = yourColor;` etc..

Comment: Did you succeed? Also: Unless you make it at least somewhat different, how will the user see the selected rowstate??

Comment: @TaW I was just going to make all the text bold. And no I haven't succeeded yet. I am going to take the color of it and add to it if its selected, if its deselected remove color. So its darker or lighter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `SelectionXxxColors` to the colors you have set for your rows.

You can use the `SelectionChanged` event to style the selected rows:

```
private void dataGridView2_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.SelectedRows)
    {
        row.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor;
        row.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = SystemColors.ControlText; 
                                               // row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor;
    }
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
        row.DefaultCellStyle.Font = row.Selected ?
            new Font(dataGridView2.Font, FontStyle.Bold) : dataGridView2.Font;
}
```

Note1 : If possible you should set the `SelectionXXXXColors` when you set the regular colors for all your rows and only change the font style when the selection changes..

Note 2: Instead of `SystemColors.ControlText` you can of course use the  `DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor` provided you have actually set it..